# Filter by entity collection. Symfony2

Tags: symfony, collections, filter, doctrine-orm

I have this entities

```
class Business
{
  ...
  /**
   * 
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="businesses")
   * 
   */
  private $categories;
  ...
}
class Category
{
  ...
  /**
   * 
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Business", mappedBy="categories")
   * 
   */
  private $businesses;
  ...
}
```

And I try this query in BusinessRepository but does not work

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

$dql = "
        SELECT a
        FROM BusinessMainBundle:Business a
        WHERE a.title LIKE :title AND :category IN (a.categories)";

$query = $em->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter("title", "%".$title."%")
            ->setParameter("category", $category);
```

If you can resolve this problem I would be thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join categories. Your DQL should look like this:

```
    $dql = "
            SELECT a
            FROM BusinessMainBundle:Business:Business a
            LEFT JOIN a.categories c
            WHERE a.title = :title AND c.id IN (:category)
    ";
```

Where

```
    ->setParameter("category", $category);
```

$category should be an array of values (in this example id of categories).